# Django 3.0: Page not found at /polls/1/{url 'polls:vote' question.id}

Tags: python, html, django, backend

I'm stuck at Django's official tutorial (see [Writing your first Django app, part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial04/)).

I get the following error:

[image]

In this Django project, inside the poll app I'm making, we're supposed to make a `vote()` view in `views.py` which should process the POST request data of the poll and redirect us to the `results()` view (there's no template for the `vote()`view, it's just in charge of processing the data we send through the poll). At first I thought I had a typo error, but I then copy-pasted everything directly out of the documentation tutorial (which I linked at the beginning of this question) and the error persisted.

My directory structure looks like this for the app:

[image]

(nevermind the errors, VSCode doesn't recognize Django'S ORM queries that's it)

My `urls.py` file looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

my `views.py` looks like this:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id)))

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
```

my `details.html` template (in which I vote and should get me redirected to the results page) looks like this:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

the `results.html` template which I should access looks like this:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

Comment: Likely you wrote in some template (not the one you show here), `{ url ... }` instead of `{% url ... %}` (notice the `%`.

Comment: I guess it was so. I rewrote everything and it basically worked.